# spring boot how to see thread pool size default value

Tags: spring-boot, threadpool, default-value

I have a spring boot application using @EnabledAsync and @Async annotations, not defining any thread pool and taking the default values.

Cheking some metrics on Grafana, it seems thread count never stop increasing and EC2 instance eventually crashes.

I know I could define thread pool size and all those values but first I'd like to know what values spring boot is using. Is there a way to see them from the code? like getThreafPoolSize() or something like that?

I tried with debug=true in property file but I couldn't see those values. Any idea?

Comment: It would be an attribute on the named Executor class, would it not?  You should set it in your application.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the default behavior in the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class of the Spring Framework.

The maximum thread pool size within the class is defined as follows.

```
private int corePoolSize = 1;

private int maxPoolSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

private int keepAliveSeconds = 60;
```

`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` details can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java).